# activity does not work as expected when it calls from an input method service

Tags: android, android-twitter

i have a activity about login twitter which works fine when i run it directly but when i call it from a input method service it does not work ...why? below is my activity code :

```
public class PostTwitter extends Activity {

private Button btnLogin;

/**
 * Register your here app https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
 * consumer key and secret
 * */
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "CfyZdyVYFeZ34nlHkjjYmHiVk";
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "QolQok2bKohLBwvctQHn1cvECQbrwWNjgrUxyoi6XgtSzHj1Gu";

// Preference Constants
static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";
private static final String PREF_USER_NAME = "twitter_user_name";

static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample_3";

// Twitter oauth urls
static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

// Twitter
private static Twitter twitter;
private static RequestToken requestToken;

// Shared Preferences
private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.post_twitter);

    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);

    // Shared Preferences
    mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPref", 0);

    /**
     * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
     * */
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                logoutFromTwitter();
            } else {
                new LoginNewUser().execute();
            }
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Function to update status
 * */
class LoginNewUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            // Tell twitter4j that we want to use it with our app
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setDebugEnabled(true);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            requestToken = twitter
                    .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            PostTwitter.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("TAG", "Arrived at onResume");
    dealWithTwitterResponse();

}
/**
 * Twitter has sent us back into our app</br> Within the intent it set back
 * we have a 'key' we can use to authenticate the user
 * 
 * @param intent
 */
private void dealWithTwitterResponse() {
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
        // If the// user// has// just// logged// in
        String oauthVerifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
        Log.d("DEBUG", "loggged in");

        new SaveTokenAfterLogin().execute(oauthVerifier);
        // authoriseNewUser(oauthVerifier);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Not logged in");
    }
}

/**
 * Create an access token for this new user</br> Fill out the Twitter4j
 * helper</br> And save these credentials so we can log the user straight in
 * next time
 * 
 * @param oauthVerifier
 */
class SaveTokenAfterLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, AccessToken> {

    @Override
    protected AccessToken doInBackground(String... oauthVerifier) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Log.d("DEBUG",oauthVerifier[0]);

        try {
            AccessToken at = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,
                    oauthVerifier[0]);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(at);

            return at;

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // Toast.makeText(this,
            // "Twitter auth error x01, try again later",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(AccessToken at) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "in post");

        String token = at.getToken();
        String secret = at.getTokenSecret();
        Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        // editor.putString(PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
        // editor.putString(PREF_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, secret);
        // editor.commit();

        editor.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, token);
        editor.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, secret);
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
        // e.putString(PREF_USER_NAME, username);
        editor.commit();
    }

}


/**
 * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
 * fetched from Shared Preferences
 * */
private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
    // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
    return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
}
/**
 * Function to logout from twitter It will just clear the application shared
 * preferences
 * */
private void logoutFromTwitter() {
    // Clear the shared preferences
    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
    e.commit();
    btnLogin.setText("Login");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully LogOut",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

//
```

}

and in my input method service i called it like this

```
        twitter_post.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Redirect to dashboard / home screen.
            oneTouchPopupDialog.dismiss();
            // make_twitter_post();
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PostTwitter.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(i);

        }

    });
```

activity is open but login does not work....any one know is there any additional code nedded which is called from service? thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean `not working?` any logs, errors, stacktraces... you are aware you have to click `btnLogin` right?

Comment: yes... the problem is in the method

    `private void dealWithTwitterResponse() {
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    }`
when the activity singly run i got expected uri but when the activity called from service and press log in the uri remain null :(